# Red and blue are swapped on Youtube

Tags: colors, youtube, flash-player, chromium

Since Sunday (April 1st), red and blue are sometimes swapped when I watch videos on YouTube.

Examples are "[Peeling Apple Like A Boss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzQDWAaxjGs&feature=player_embedded)" (blue arms and apple) or, to my dismay, the famous Red vs. Blue series ([like this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjMYb6lyrmM&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=SL)) which sucks.

[Here](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/7787/screenshot2ef.png) is a screenshot of the RvB episode at 1:28.

Vimeo is OK, other web video services are OK, only most YouTube videos are affected ... well, all that I could find so far.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PonKeBVyABI&feature=player_embedded) looks OK in Firefox but it's broken in Chrome. The episode of RvB looks wrong in both browsers. Local videos look file.

What could be causing this?

**[EDIT]** Versions:

openSUSE 12.1
NVIDIA 295.33
Firefox 11.0
Chromium 17.0.922.0
Flash 11.0.1.152

Comment: Sounds like a clever prank on Red vs. Blue fans. :)

Comment: can you provide us with actual screenshots?

Comment: Which operating system? Which version of Google Chrome?

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Yeah, thought the same ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could have to do with hardware acceleration.

If you are using Flash:

1. Right click on the video, go to Settings and in the first tab toggle the acceleration checkmark.
2. Go to http://www.youtube.com/testtube and enable HTML5.

If you are using HTML5:

2. Go to http://www.youtube.com/testtube and disable HTML5.
3. Right click on the Flash video, go to Settings and in the first tab toggle the acceleration checkmark.

Comment: Does the acceleration checkmark have an effect immediately or do I have to close the dialog or restart the browser?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I think refresh the page, but you could try restarting the browser to be sure.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that tonight.

Comment: HWAccel did it for me. HTML5 video also works.

Comment: clearing HWAccell finally fixed this for me. HTML5 wasn't an option because it wasn't just youtube that was going into Avatar mode

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable the new included Flash plugin. It's new and is causing some problems on Linux, not least on amd64 systems.

1. Go to `chrome://plugins`
2. Press "Details"
3. "Disable" the Flash with type: "PPAPI" (the other should have type: "NPAPI))

and reload the Youtube page and see if it differs. If so, it is a bug in the new "Pepper Flash" that comes with Chrome and Chromium (on some distributions). If not, activate the internal Flash version again (it is the only one receiving updates on the Linux platform from now on).

(Note: when I click "Disable", the page doesn't react, but if I reload the `chrome://plugins` page the change is shown.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't disable hardware acceleration, because for some reason, I can't change any settings, but I've found a workaround which works for me: I've downloaded the firefox addon ["DownloadHelper"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/), and the colors in the downloaded videos are OK.

You can also try out "YouTube Leanback", which you can find by clicking on "Try something new" on the bottom of the YouTube Page, the colors are alright for me there.

edit: The best workaround is to just watch it on tubereplay.com!

Comment: Downloading every video might not be feasible in some situations. Nice to hear that Lean-back works though. +1

Comment: Did you do the mms.conf hack first? Undo that and you can disable it.

Comment: No, I didn't. I have a new Ubuntu installation now, and now it works, but in the old one, it was just impossible to click on anything in the flashplayer settings pop-up. I could use tab to highlight options, but pressing enter would do nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that's an other bug in Flash; what a shame you got both. :(

Comment: Well, at least everything works since I've reinstalled my OS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try (work for me):

```
mkdir /etc/adobe
echo -e "EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=1\nOverrideGPUValidation=true" > /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

Comment: Don't do this, this makes your flash player unstable!