# Hue shift on youtube.com (but not when embedded!)

Tags: video, youtube, embedded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Red and blue are swapped on Youtube](https://superuser.com/questions/407787/red-and-blue-are-swapped-on-youtube)

This is easily the oddest problem I've yet had. When I'm on youtube, and I look at a video, the hue is all wrong. Pure red becomes pure blue, and all the other colors shift accordingly. Faces in particular are shades of blue so I call this "avatar mode".

Avatar mode happens on any video I view while on youtube.com. BUT, if I view the same video when embedded, colors are fine!

**Embedded:**

[image: embedded]

**YouTube:**

[image: youtube]

**EDIT:** OS: Gentoo Linux, happens in all browsers

Comment: What OS + browser are you using?  Does this occur in multiple browsers?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, Gentoo Linux, and yes it occurs in both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Honestly no idea but what happens on different resolutions? and have you emerged the latest graphics driver? (and which one are you using?)

Comment: How about trying HTML5 video (http://youtube.com/html5)? What about other sites that use Flash based video (e.g. http://dailymotion.com)? Heh, funny coincidence, when testing this my display drivers crashed.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch I'm using the latest nvidia drivers, it's resolution independent.

Comment: @Bob daily motion the colors are fine, and switching to youtube's html5 trial fixes the colors, thanks!

Comment: @Mala how about other flash-based videos?

Comment: I have the same problem but it has been occurred since many weeks. I'm using Gentoo too and it occurs on all browsers with Flash Player.